# Download all mp3 file in RSS feed

Tags: download, http

Using a Windows 10 PC, I'd like to download all mp3 files listed in the enclosure tags of an rss feed.

I tried HTTRack and http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/12756/download-files-linked-in-a-rss-feed but had no luck with either.

Anyone know of other alternatives?

Comment: I'd probably go for Powershell being on Windows.  Here is an example: https://phejndorf.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/download-from-an-rss-feed-with-powershell/ Hard to be more specific without seeing the XML of the feed but that should get you going.  Looking at the code, the call to DownloadString on the second line has the URL, which you will presumably change.  This should be within double-quotes, i.e. "link".  In the example, the second double quote has been escaped to `&quot;`.

Comment: This is perfect! Can you add as an answer so I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you are on the Windows platform, the best choice here without resorting to third-party utilities is probably Powershell.  It can download files from a URL and has good parsing of XML.  If you need an example, the following should be helpful:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Mix11VideosDownloadThemAllWithRSS.aspx